# How to use a batch file on multiple adb devices simultaneously?

Tags: android, batch-file, cmd, adb

I am trying to use a batch file on multiple adb devices simultaneously via cmd.

How do I set a variable named *serial* and use `adb -s` to run commands to all devices attached?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in order to take a screencap over multiple indeterminate devices;

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
REM Some Variables To Create Directories with
set VERSION=APPVERSION
set TEST=TESTNAME
REM used to remove 'device' from each line
set "replace=device"
set "replaced="
set "source=test.txt"
set "target=clean.txt"
REM adb command to grab all connected devices
adb devices > adb.txt
REM Used to generate a filename friendly datetime
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') do set datetime=%%I
set datetime=%datetime:~0,8%-%datetime:~8,6%
REM Strip everything except the device ID/Serial Number
findstr /v "List of devices attached" adb.txt > test.txt
(
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %source%') do (
      set "line=%%b"
      if defined line set "line=!line:%replace%=%replaced%!"
      echo(!line!)
) > %target%
REM with the 'clean' file of just device IDs, set them as elements of an array
set idi=0
for /F "usebackq" %%A in (clean.txt) do (
    SET /A idi=!idi! + 1
    set var!idi!=%%A
)
set var
REM now the true work can begin
REM we use the device ids to take and save a screenshot from each device
REM we are putting the screenshots into a device specific folder in VERSION\TEST directory
REM the screenshot name is formatted as 'deviceID-datetime.ping'
for /L %%x in (1, 1, %idi%) do (
if not exist "%UserProfile%\Desktop\%VERSION%\%TEST%\!var%%x!" mkdir %UserProfile%\Desktop\%VERSION%\%TEST%\!var%%x!
adb -s !var%%x! shell screencap -p /sdcard/!var%%x!-%datetime%.png
adb -s !var%%x! pull /sdcard/!var%%x!-%datetime%.png %UserProfile%\Desktop\%VERSION%\%TEST%\!var%%x!
adb -s !var%%x! shell rm /sdcard/!var%%x!-%datetime%.png
)
```

The part you're likely most concerned with is the part that indentifies for you all the connected devices Serial Numbers to use in the command you wish to execute on each device;

```
REM used to remove 'device' from each line
set "replace=device"
set "replaced="
set "source=test.txt"
set "target=clean.txt"
REM adb command to grab all connected devices
adb devices > adb.txt
findstr /v "List of devices attached" adb.txt > test.txt
(
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %source%') do (
      set "line=%%b"
      if defined line set "line=!line:%replace%=%replaced%!"
      echo(!line!)
) > %target%
REM with the 'clean' file of just device IDs, set them as elements of an array
set idi=0
for /F "usebackq" %%A in (clean.txt) do (
    SET /A idi=!idi! + 1
    set var!idi!=%%A
)
set var
```

From there you can just modify the last bit to include your command;

```
for /L %%x in (1, 1, %idi%) do (
adb -s !var%%x! shell <command>)
```

There may be a 'cleaner' way of doing this, but this works for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing it

**way #1:**

Batch file name: testbat.bat

```
SET adbserial=%1
adb -s %adbserial% reboot
adb -s %adbserial% wait-for-device
adb -s %adbserial% root
```

run it as `testbat.bat 123456`, where 123456 is your adb serial number

**way #2:**

1. Open command prompt
2. SET ANDROID_SERIAL 123456 , where 123456 is your one of device's adb serial number
3. run your batch script without any modifications.

That particular command prompt can talk to only device with serial number '123456'